# Re-Arrange an NxN grid to find all possible combinations of square positions

Tags: geometry, combinations

Hey guys I am trying to solve a problem, so consider the following grids:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMM1p.jpg

I need to re-arrange the grids to find all possible combinations. Regarding the 2x2 grid, I attempted the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rO79.jpg

1. Swap A with B, reset, swap A with C, reset, swap A with D, reset
2. Swap B with C, reset, swap B with D, reset
3. Swap C with D

My approach is to swap each letter with the others once and then reset position. However there is a flaw to this approach... I am missing combinations such as top left B, top right A, bottom left D, bottom right C.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method that is not optimal.

Convert the square $n$ by $n$
to a $n^2$ by 
using a snake-like pattern.
For example,
the 2 by 2 would be
"ABDC"
and the
3 by 3 would be
"ABCFEDGHI".

Then,
generate all permutations of these.
For each permutation,
reform the square.

Actually,
thinking about it,
the way that 
the square is unfolded
doesn't matter
as long as all permutations are generated.
So unfolding as
"ABCDEFGHI" would work
just fine.

As for the time,
since the m! permutations
of m items can be
generated by swapping
with,
on average,
less than 2 swaps
per permutation,
the total time would be
less than $2\cdot (n^2)!$
swaps.

Here is a reference:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm

Comment: Rearrange the $n$ by $n$ square to a $n^2$ by $1$ array.

Comment: So transform everything into one row? But why is the 2x2 starting position ABDC as opposed to ABCD?

Comment: Because I originally thought of doing a snake-like rearrangement, but then realized it was not necessary, and decided to leave in my original argument.

Comment: So the approach is to start as ABCD, and then find all the possible permutations? That is ABCD, BACD, CBAD, DBCA,so on... And then put each possibility as a square?

Comment: Yep. That's my idea.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! much appreciated!